# Code being executed after completion handler is called

Tags: ios, swift

Why is this continuing after the completion handler is called?

See the comments in the code. See the code path to get to #1. At this point I'm expecting the code to call the completion handler complete(), and return from the function, preventing execution of #2. However, code at #2 still appears to be getting triggered. Any ideas why this os occurring?

```
func syncSessionLog(withCompletion complete: @escaping ((Bool, String?) -> Void)) {

    ... bunch of code

        managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
            let trackFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Track.fetchRequest()
            let trackPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == \(session.track_id)")

            trackFetchRequest.predicate = trackPredicate
            trackFetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

            do {
                let foundTrack = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(trackFetchRequest) as! [Track]
                if foundTrack.count < 1 {
                    self.debug.log(tag: "SessionManager", content: "not found tID: \(session.track_id)")

                    //#1 When not found, complete is called, yet the code still manages to reach "do stuff" down the bottom.

                    complete(false, "Not found")
                    return
                }

                associatedTrack = foundTrack[0]
            }
            catch {
                self.debug.log(tag: "SessionManager", content: "Failed to get Track object from Core Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                fatalCoreDataError(error)
                complete(false, "Failed to retrieve")
            }
        }

        //#2 do stuff with associatedTrack
```

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?  Your catch function calls `complete` and doesn't return (so execution would flow to #2).

Comment: return will let you out of the waiting block only. and #2 will continue on the flow. If you want to block the execution after the completion, you need a boolean flag outside the waiting function. Change its value according to your own logic and then at #2 check the value of the flag and proceed if you need. Don't forget to declare the flag as block.

Comment: Nope, `associatedTrack` is set to nil. :/ I hackishly solved if by checking if `associatedTrack` is nil before continuing on. However, I'd like to figure out whats really going on here.

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal there is no need for `__block` in Swift.

Comment: sorry i was used in swift 2 so written in the flow...thats a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` will exit out of the current context, which is the closure associated with the `performAndWait`.  After that closure returns, execution continues with the next statement after `performAndWait` which is whatever is at #2.

You can move the code from point #2 *inside* the closure

Comment: Shouldn't that `complete()` call stop execution from ever reaching the `return` anyway?

Comment: No.  `complete` calls the completion handler, but after the completion handler returns, you are back at the statement after the completion handler call, which is the `return` - but that simply exits the closure.

Comment: ohhhh. I expected calling a completion handler to return as well as execute the closure.

Comment: Nope, calling a completion handler is just like any another function call.  You could call the variable `fred` and then say `fred(false, "Not Found")` with the same result.

Comment: Ah, I now need to go through and check all my completion handlers haha.

Comment: the same i assumed...the return will only get out of the waiting block... :)

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple - the `return` statement is inside a block, so it returns from the block, not from the outside method. It would be more visible if the block had some return value.

As such, this `return` is not needed in your code. You will need to set a `Bool` flag to indicate the result of block execution and act accoridngly in #2.

Comment: Shouldn't that `complete()` call stop execution from ever reaching the `return` anyway?

Comment: No, why? `complete()` is another block and is not a keyword for the language. Its name may be misleading, but its just a naming convention. It could very well be named `inform()` or anything else. You should think of blocks as of methods. You would'nt expect the code to stop, if you called `self.complete()`, would you?

Comment: Thanks, I up voted you, as I couldn't accept you both. Thanks.